# Installing custom packages inside a python venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-venv

I need to install some custom python tools into my python virtual environment. I can install them fine globally.

The venv was created by running `python3 -m venv env`

My files are laid out like this:

tool/
|-setup.py
project/
|-env/
|-|-bin/

I've installed globally by going to `tool/` and running `python3 setup.py` this works great and I can then open a python terminal and type `import tool` and everything works.

So now I need to use it in the virtual env. First thing I tried was navigating to project/env/bin and running `python3 ~//tool/setup.py` which didn't throw errors but when I enter a python shell and try `import tool` I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'tool'`

Next I tried activating the venv with `source evn/bin/activate` navigating to `tool/` and installing just like I would globally by running `python3 setup.py` which again throws no errors and gives a success message but doesn't work in a python shell.

My questions are: is this at all the correct way to install something into a venv when not using pip? and if so, what did I break and how can I fix my setup to work?

Comment: What's in the setup.py file? What's the connection to the "project" directory? Setup files are not supposed to install projects in different folders, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do :/ I didn't realize you couldn't install to other folders.